# Powermock + Mockito + Testng implementation not working

Tags: mockito, testng, powermock, powermockito

So I'm basing my implementation on this site "http://www.handverdrahtet.org/2012/10/unittest-to-verify-that-static-method.html" but it's giving me an error:

```
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Test set: TestSuite
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Tests run: 3, Failures: 2, Errors: 0, Skipped: 1, Time elapsed: 1.675 s <<< FAILURE! - in TestSuite
com.example.Activity1Test.shouldShowInputDialogOnUpdateTextButtonClick  Time elapsed: 0.005 s  <<< FAILURE!
java.lang.reflect.InaccessibleObjectException: Unable to make protected native java.lang.Object java.lang.Object.clone() throws java.lang.CloneNotSupportedException accessible: module java.base does not "opens java.lang" to unnamed module @30cb5b99
    at com.example.Activity1Test.shouldShowInputDialogOnUpdateTextButtonClick(Activity1Test.java)

com.example.Activity1Test.afterPowerMockTestMethod  Time elapsed: 0.007 s  <<< FAILURE!
java.lang.reflect.InaccessibleObjectException: Unable to make protected native java.lang.Object java.lang.Object.clone() throws java.lang.CloneNotSupportedException accessible: module java.base does not "opens java.lang" to unnamed module @4089713
```

**Here is the test() function I used in my Test file:**

```
public void test(String msg) {
   JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter a string.");
}
```

**Here is the current Test file:**

```
package com.example;

import static org.mockito.Mockito.*;
import static org.powermock.api.mockito.PowerMockito.*;

import javax.swing.*;
import org.powermock.core.classloader.annotations.PrepareForTest;
import org.powermock.modules.testng.PowerMockTestCase;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

@PrepareForTest(JOptionPane.class)
public class Activity1Test extends PowerMockTestCase {
    /**
     * Unittest to verify that static method is called with the specified parameter.
     */

    @Test
    public void shouldShowInputDialogOnUpdateTextButtonClick() {
        mockStatic(JOptionPane.class);

        Activity1 activity1 = new Activity1();
        activity1.test("foo");

        verifyStatic(JOptionPane.class);
        JOptionPane.showInputDialog("foo");
    }
}
```

Comment: You test will fail because your `test(String msg)` method doesn't use `msg` but a static string instead. 
About the errors, I think you should include more details.

Comment: @thchp So I tried commenting out the codes inside the `shouldShowInputDialogOnUpdateTextButtonClick` function, but the error still persists. And unfortunately, it only gives me that error and nothing else so I cannot include more details about the error :/